# Use of dbms_sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

This piece of code does not work but I dont know why :

```
set serveroutput on buffer 2560000
declare
requete varchar2(4000);
name_firm varchar2(35);
curseur_ref number;
response number;

begin
    curseur_ref := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    requete := 'SELECT trim(myTable.myColumn) from myTable';

    dbms_sql.parse(curseur_ref, requete, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.define_column(curseur_ref, 1, name_firm, 35);
    response := dbms_sql.execute(curseur_ref);
    dbms_sql.column_value(curseur_ref, 1, name_firm);
    dbms_output.put_line('NB enregs : ' || dbms_sql.fetch_rows(curseur_ref));
    dbms_output.put_line('name_firm : ' || name_firm);
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(curseur_ref);
end;
```

There is no plsql error

The result is :

NB enregs : 1 (it found one... which is correct)

name_firm : 'there is nothing but a name exists'

The request is good as I can send it alone and have the name of the firm

What is going on?

Thank you for answering

Note : the thing is that I saw this code work once....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `column_value` call in the wrong place; it needs to be after the fetch:

```
...
    response := dbms_sql.execute(curseur_ref);
--    dbms_sql.column_value(curseur_ref, 1, name_firm);
    dbms_output.put_line('NB enregs : ' || dbms_sql.fetch_rows(curseur_ref));
    dbms_sql.column_value(curseur_ref, 1, name_firm);
    dbms_output.put_line('name_firm : ' || name_firm);
...
```

Which gives:

```
NB enregs : 1
name_firm : some val
```

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23448/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68196):

> Call COLUMN_VALUE Procedure or COLUMN_VALUE_LONG Procedure to determine the value of a column retrieved by the FETCH_ROWS Function
>   for your query

It's also shown in [their third example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23448/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68202).

The only way i can see you'd have seen it working in the past is if it used to be in a loop fetching multiple rows, in which case you'd see a null value for the first one and the previous row's value for the rest.

Of course, there's no need to use dynamic SQL for this, but I assume this is a stripped down example to demonstrate the issue.